# Is there a way to create an Azure virtual machine which uses an ARM CPU as opposed to x86/64?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I haven't seen options for creating an ARM based CPU when creating a virtual machine. Perhaps I am missing something when looking?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you find an answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, Azure Virtual machine supports **Intel and AMD** CPUs for various types of Virtual Machines

As of now, Azure Virtual Machines does not provide **ARM** CPU

You can find the list of CPUs offering for different types of Azure Virtual Machines from below:

[Compute benchmark scores for Azure Windows VMs - Azure Virtual Machines | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/compute-benchmark-scores)